# Xpath Extract data from Parent element and not its child elements where parent name is same as child

Tags: postgresql-9.5, xpath-2.0

Parent and child tags have same name. I am trying to extract everything from parent except for the child elements.

We have several rows in parent that we want to extract. There are several Parent and child which are nested as below.

Have tried //Record/preceding-sibling::* which does not give me parent element start and end tag.
[not(descendant::Record)] and many other alternatives but no luck.

```
<Record contentId="1"> 
    <Metrics_Library_Name>Text1</Metrics_Library_Name>  
    <Metrics_Library_ID>1</Metrics_Library_ID>  
    <Record contentId="1a"> 
        <Questionnaire_ID>1a</Questionnaire_ID>  
        <Year>2018</Year>  
        <Quarter/>  
        <Month>02-Feb</Month> 
    </Record>  
    <Record contentId="1b"> 
        <Questionnaire_ID>1a</Questionnaire_ID>  
        <Year>2018</Year>  
        <Quarter/>  
        <Month>02-Feb</Month> 
    </Record> 
</Record>
```

Expected output:

```
<Record contentId="1"> 
    <Metrics_Library_Name>Text1</Metrics_Library_Name>  
    <Metrics_Library_ID>1</Metrics_Library_ID> 
</Record>
```

Comment: <Parent1 Record> <Text1> <Text2>...<Child1 Record><Text1></Child1> <Text2><Child2 Record>... </Child2> 
</Parent1 Record>
<Parent2 Record> <Text1> <Text2>...<Child1 Record><Text1> <Text2></Child1><Child2 Record>...</Child2>
</Parent2 Record>

Comment: XPath selects nodes but XPath is read-only -- it cannot **delete** children of a selected node.

Use XSLT to get the stated wanted result